# Why is the final value undefined for the for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am new to JavaScript and as I was practising I was not able to figure out why does the last value in my `oddPairs` array returns `undefined` when the loop ends?

```js
const people = 56;
let numberGenerator = 0
let tickets = [];
let evenPais = [];
let oddPairs = [];

for (let counter = 1; counter <= people; counter++){
    let numberGenerator = Math.ceil(Math.random() *56);
    tickets.push(numberGenerator);
}

for (let i = 1; i <= people; i++){
    if (tickets[i] % 2 === 0){
        evenPais.push(tickets[i]);
    }else {
        oddPairs.push(tickets[i]);
    }
}

console.log(evenPais);
console.log(oddPairs);
console.log(evenPais.length + oddPairs.length);
```

Comment: Array indexing starts from zero.

Answer (score 2):

your code:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= people; i++){
```

solution:

```
for (let i = 0; i < people; i++){
```

Comment: for (let i = 1; i < people; i++){ it will also work no need to put i=0

Comment: @Wajid except that omits the first element in `tickets`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Array always starts with 0 and ends with n - 1.

```js
const people = 56;
let numberGenerator = 0
let tickets = [];
let evenPais = [];
let oddPairs = [];

for (let counter = 1; counter <= people; counter++){
    let numberGenerator = Math.ceil(Math.random() *56);
    tickets.push(numberGenerator);
}

for (let i = 0; i < people; i++){
    if (tickets[i] % 2 === 0){
        evenPais.push(tickets[i]);
    }else {
        oddPairs.push(tickets[i]);
    }
}

console.log(evenPais);
console.log(oddPairs);
console.log(evenPais.length + oddPairs.length);
```

Comment: Not sure , you can start array from 1 , here issue is he is putting equal in loop

Comment: In that case you can't get first index value until you do index-1

Answer (score 1):

You have to start your array index (in your case the Counter) from zero, and end your loop when Counter equal People -1.

Comment: can start from 1 no issue if you start from 1 just need to set i < people; this condion

Answer (score 0):

It is because your added wrong loop condition

what it mean of your conditon `for (let i = 1; i <= people; i++){`  it mean it will run at last index of array so suppose you have length of array is **3** but in array start of index from **0** so it will finish on **2** now when again **3<=3** here **i** now is 3 so condition true and loop will run and when loop go in then it find undefine index mean **3** is not index of your array

**Solution is**

you need to set like this `for (let i = 1; i < people; i++){` now at last iteration when i=3 **3<3** then this condition will false now loop will break

hope this will help for you to understand working of loop

Comment: `for (let i = 1; i < people; i++)` will not go through `tickets[0]` so `evenPais.length + oddPairs.length` will be 55 instead of 56